# Android how to check php message to validate login

Tags: java, php, android

I want to figure out how to use php message response to validate login,here is my login php:

```
<?php 
    include 'connectdb.php';

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $kodeDosen =$data["kodeDosen"];
    $password = $data["password"];

    $message = array("message"=>"Data found");
    $failure = array("mesage"=>"Data not found");

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT kodeDosen, namaDosen, email, telepon FROM tbl_dosen WHERE kodeDosen =? and password = ?")) {

       /* bind parameters for markers */
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $kodeDosen,$password);

       /* execute query */
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

       /* store result */
       mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

       if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
          echo json_encode($message);
       }else {
          echo json_encode($failure);
       }

    }

?>
```

and here is the exerpt to my login java:

```
public class loginDosen extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txKodeDosen,txPassword;
    String KodeDosen,password;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String loginURL ="http://192.168.43.217/test/DosenPublikasi/registerDosen.php";
    StringRequest request;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_dosen);

        txKodeDosen = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txKodeDosen);
        txPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txPassword);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(loginDosen.this);
    }

    public void Login(View view) {

        if (txKodeDosen.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Kode Dosen Field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (txKodeDosen.getText().toString().charAt(0) != 'D') {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Must have D in the start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (txKodeDosen.length() != 5) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Must be 5 characters long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (txPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password Field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            JSONObject Login = new JSONObject();
            try {
                Login.put("kodeDosen", txKodeDosen.getText().toString());
                Login.put("password", txPassword.getText().toString());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JsonObjectRequest jsonobjectrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginURL, Login,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()

                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Toast.makeText(loginDosen.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SharedPreferences DataDosen = getSharedPreferences("Dosen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = DataDosen.edit();
                            editor.putString("kodeDosen", txKodeDosen.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("password", txPassword.getText().toString());
                            editor.commit();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(loginDosen.this, homepageDosen.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(loginDosen.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });
            requestQueue.add(jsonobjectrequest);


        }
    }
```

From another question i asked,they say that i still used the response from the php and put it on a toast but doesnt do anything with it.I want to find a way to use the php response to validate my login prompt,as when i tried using the code that other user gave me,it resulted in a unhandled expression error

Comment: `if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
          echo json_encode($message);
       }else {
          echo json_encode($failure);
       }`
here you return different response depending on result from the database. Check for this response in your Java

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to handle this. The best and advised way is to set response header. For an example, in case of successful login, you can set the response code to 200 or 401 in case of failed login.

You can set header as such (just before `echo`):

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Then in your client side i.e. Android you can check for response code and plan your actions according to response code.